# Upload an Applet to a real smart card using APDU

Tags: java, applet, smartcard, java-io, apdu

i have created an applet using Java Card Development Kit (Java Card 3.0.2 Runtime),i used `scriptgen` to generate to script APDU , then i want to run `apdutool` with the generated apdu script file to upload the applet in a real smart card on a real card reader connected to my computer over USB.
i run this command :

```
apdutool -s pcsc myScriptApdu
```

but i got this error :

```
Opening connection to local reader on port pcsc.
Error: Cannot open port.
Available ports:
<none available>
```

is it possible what i want to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible but you first need to make sure your reader device is installed as PC/SC compatible smart card reader (this is most easy if it is configured as a CCID compatible reader).

Comment: You can look in the registry under "Calais" or you could list them using [some tool](http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-tools/) (also look at bottom of that page). Finally, it's easy to find them using the SmartCardIO library in Java, which also defaults to PC/SC compatible readers.

Comment: I used to use this card reader to read smart card using c# as a PC/SC reader,  so I am sure it's a compatible one

Comment: Try using Java, list all the smart card readers. If that cannot find it, I presume the tool will fail as well. By the way, I don't see any -s option in the 3.0.5 documentation; can you try without the -s pcsc? I think PCSC / T=1 should be the default anyway (I don't use it myself).

Comment: whe i use java to list all readers it's working , i have all readers connected to my pc , but still can't make apdutool load the applet to a card using the reader 
`apdutool scriptAPDU-Download
ApduTool [v3.0.5]
    Copyright (c) 1998, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.


Opening connection to localhost on port 9025.
Connected.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

Comment: Did you try without the `-s` option? If I read the documentation correctly that may not be needed.

Comment: i did try without -s option , i got what's in my previous comment